# Stylus missing styles when compiled

Tags: css, stylus

If you take a look at the stylus snippet below, when `bottom 0` is added, the height from the below doesn't get compiled into CSS. Remove `bottom 0` and it works fine, unfortunately I need `bottom 0` in this case:

**Stylus**

```
&__text-mask
        span
            display block
            position absolute
            z-index 10
            left 0
            right 0
            height 18px
            bottom 0
            background rgba(255,0,0,.5)
```

**Resulting CSS**

```
.bioink-carousel__text-mask span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

I have also recreated this behaviour in a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/wickywills/pen/eMOPzm). Am I missing something here? I have no errors in the console when compiling. I also notice that if you move `bottom 0` to a different line, other styles get missed. Very odd.

Comment: As a temporary workaround I have converted it to a CSS literal due to the time restrictions on my project, however that is certainly not ideal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you had a couple of spaces instead of tab, I think before the height declaration. Or something like that. I have re-tabbed all the properties and now works as it should

```
/* just so SO allows me to link to codepen... */
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jzNejb

Comment: Strange, in my project I couldn't see any spaces, but I re-tabbed everything like you suggested and it worked fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You had some invisible charachters in your code. Codepen even showed th red "info" icon at bottom right to warn that there is "unexpected indent". Anyway here is the code that works:

https://codepen.io/ivandoric/pen/dmbgBK

```
&__text-mask
    span
       display: block;
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 10;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       height: 18px;
       bottom: 0;
       background: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
```